# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to access the Application Center manangment console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I was going through [this IBM Worklight Information Center article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/t_starting_the_application_cente.html) to access the Application Center management console, but the URL mentioned is not working. Is there any other proper guideline available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL provided seems correct.
What error do you see in the browser window when the loading of this URL fails?

- Did you install Worklight using the IBM Installation Mananger?
- Assuming that "yes", as this is the only installation path for Application Center

  - What did you choose as your underlying application server?
  - Did you start the application server?

IBM Worklight Application Center is **not provided** with the Developer Edition, installable via the Eclipse Marketplace and IBM Worklight website.

Comment: No I have installed worklight by only updating the plugin in eclipse and it is giving me all the options.

Comment: Mu console is opening fine. App is deploying and all. But as described in the links I've seen through the preference. The same localhost:9080/applicationcenter should work right ? Or I am missing something ?

Comment: IBM Worklight Application Center is NOT available from the Developer Edition installation you have performed. You hae to PURCHASE a license of Worklight and install it using the IBM Installation Manager, which then also provides you the IBM Worklight Application Center.